# Given 2 points/coordinates, how do I express in $ax + by + c = 0$ form?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Given 2 points eg. $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ how do I express in $ax + by + c$ form?

---

I am supposed to find the intersection of 2 lines. I have 2 points for 1 line, and the other line will be something like $y=10$. I think my maths is very rusty and don't really get it ...

[image]

I guess $t$ is a variable, $x_i, y_i$ values are given, but whats $a, b, c$?

Comment: Seems overly fancy. Here is the high school version. If $x_1=x_2=a$, the line has equation $x=a$, or equivalently $x-a=0$. If $x_1\ne x_2$, then the line has slope $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. Call this $m$. Then the line has equation of shape $y=mx+b$. Substitute $x=x_1$, $y=y_1$. We get $y_1=mx_1+b$. Now you know $b$, and can write down the equation of the line.

Comment: That was not the question.  A line $ax+by=c$ is *given* and one wants to compute the intersection of that line and a given line-segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the segment as a line that passes through $p_0$ and $p_1$. Find the slope of that line. You can denote it as $m$ and find using the following formula:

$$m = \frac{y_0-y_1}{x_0-x_1}$$

Then you can find the equation of that line using the same formula:

$$y - y_0 = m(x - x_1)$$

And you'll get an equation for the line of the tupe $Ax + By + C = 0$

Once you find them solve the following system of equations:

$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&Ax + By + C = 0\\
&ax + by + c = 0
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

A,B,C and a,b,c are coefficient in the equation of the line that define that line.